# How come selectors in $.fn.find() cannot reference the tree beyond the current $ scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal, jquery-traversing

In jQuery

```
$('html head').length                             // 1
```

And

```
$('html').find('head').length                     // 1
```

And

```
$('html').find('head').filter('html head').length // 1
```

BUT

```
$('html').find('html head').length                // 0
```

Why?

Comment: Just leaving this one here: `$('html').andSelf().find('html head').length`

Comment: @epascarello thanks! I would've accepted that as an answer, TBH — it was by trying `$('body').andSelf().find('html p').length === 0` that I realised jQuery essentially ignores everything above the current scope for the purposes of `find`.

Comment: I really don't understand meaning of this. Why not just use: $(document).find('html head').length then?

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but what would be the purpose of `find()` if it didn't search within context?

Comment: @Mathletics it absolutely should! I wouldn't expect `$('html').find('html body')` to retrieve anything, for instance. But the element described by `html head` is always within the context of `html`.

Comment: Now I'm doubly confused; what is special about `$('html').find('html head')` vs `$('html').find('html body')`?

Comment: @Mathletics sorry, I'm getting muddled. `html head` was too simple an example. I would expect `$('body').find('html.lt-ie9 div')` to work (*if* the html did indeed have that class), for example. But this question isn't about use case, it's about jQuery's internal mechanisms.

Comment: Based on your logic, `$('li').find('div a')` would return anchors that were direct children of `li`, provided the `li` was nested in a `div` (in addition to the standard matched set of anchors within divs within list items.)

Comment: Here, I made a fiddle to show how wacky this is: http://jsfiddle.net/PdxSb/1/

Comment: @Mathletics yes, that's what I'm talking about. It was tough, but I got there in the end ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first selector `$('html head')` works just like find - gets any `<head>` descendants of HTML

```
HTML──┐  start here and find head
    HEAD
```

Your second selector `$('html').find('head')` gets html element - then finds all descendant `<head>` elements

```
HTML──┐ start here and find head
    HEAD
```

Your third selector `$('html').find('head').filter('html head')`  gets html element - then finds all descendant `<head>` elements - the filter is really pointless because the returned `head` elements are guaranteed to be descendants of `html` because of this `$('html').find('head')`

```
HTML──┐  start here and find head
    HEAD
```

Your lastone that isn't working `$('html').find('html head')` is searching for structure below

```
HTML──┐  start here and find "html head" 
    HTML──┐    
         HEAD
but really your structure is like this
HTML──┐  
    HEAD
```

which html doesn't have a descendant html element so that results in 0 elements returned

If you want to keep the HTML element in the collection you can use [.addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/)

```
$('html') // get html element
  .find('html head') // find head element
  .addBack() // add back the html element
  // if jQuery 1.7 and lower use .andSelf()
  .length  // this will result in 1 element - the HTML element
```

Answer (score 7):

Because there is no `<html>` tag nested inside `<html>` tag

But:

```
$('html').find('html, head').length // return 1 here coz comma means 'or'
```

Comment: I'm not looking for the `html` tag, I'm looking for a `head` tag that is a descendant of an `html` tag (ie `html head`) inside the `html` tag. Essentially, I want the same thing as what the first 3 expressions return.

Comment: So just: $('html').find('head')   Why not use it?

Comment: How come selectors in $.fn.find() cannot reference the tree beyond the current $ scope?

Comment: `html head` *is* a descendant of `head` though. Using `html` && `head` was a bad example in hindsight — too simple. There is no purpose to it here — the question is in the title: I wasn't honestly trying to find the `html` tag for Christ's sake (well done on the upvotes though!).

Answer (score 5):

Per the documentation:

Find: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

`HTML` is not a descendant of `HTML`

http://api.jquery.com/find/